# How to store image to sql database using Data Access Layer (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

## I have a Data Access Layer

```
public void AddPartyAsIndividual(AddAnIndividual Student)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddIndividualParty", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        md.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Student_Image", STudent.StudentImage);

        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Comment: a DAL, is an extra library that we use to help us with the database actions. Now your question is very poor, nether I see any dal. What error did you have ? where this is not work ?. what is the store procedure ? what DAL did you use ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following Codeproject article. It demonstrates how to store and retrieve images via SQL Server. The example used is a Winforms client, but the code can be adapted to any project type.

[Storing and Retrieving Images from SQL Server Using Strored Procedures and C#.net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/354639/Storing-and-Retrieving-Images-from-SQL-Server-Usin)